# How do I install a Windows Service programatically with additional args?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm attempting to install a service via C# from an installer's custom action.

I've tracked most of the topics related to my problem on Stack-Overflow however I've failed to find a solution to my problem.

The problem is : I need to pass additional arguments to my service, here's how it looks like in cmd.exe :

```
my_service -installMY_SERVICE_NAME cmdLine="commands in here" auxCommands="aux commands in here"
net start "My Service (MY_SERVICE_NAME)"
```

It works if I do it from the command line however I fail to get it done in C# therefore I'm forced to ask for help

Regards

Comment: What works from the command line? If it runs in the command line, but doesn't run in Visual Studio, then take a look at the Debug page for the project properties page -- there should be an option to enter the command line arguments there when the debugger is kicked off.

Comment: it's not a matter of "not working" in VS. I have no idea how to get it done in the first place. I've imported the advapi32.dll's interface into C# however I have NO IDEA how to pass start parameters.

Comment: Are you trying to pass parameters when the service is being started? If so I don't think that is possible. Passing parameters while installing certainly is

Comment: and how do I do that exactly?

Comment: The answer that I provided shows you how to pass paramteres while installing with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to start a service via the command line with C# and pass in additional arguments. [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx) has parameters for command line arguments. Give this a try

```
Process.Start("my_service", "-install MY_SERVICE_NAME cmdLine=\"commands in here\"" auxCommands=\"aux commands in here\");
Process.Start("net", "start \"My Service (MY_SERVICE_NAME)\"");
```

Comment: That's one way to do it, however I need to do this programmatically

Comment: That is a programmatic solution, that is valid C#

Comment: Well it works so I'll tag it as an answer - although this is not exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Would this be what you are looking for, to start a service from C#? The [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WindowsServicesInAction1.aspx) here on CodeProject might do the trick?

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no mention about passing additional arguments/start parameters to the service in there