# Service or console app that runs in the background?

Tags: .net, service, transparency

Create a service or console app that runs in the background?

I want to create a .net app that runs every time at startup and runs in the background like a service. I am not trying to make a sneaky app or spyware, just a background process.

My concern with making a service is users have to know how to log in to the service that first time and set it up. If the app were run by lot's of people that would probably fail many times.

Is there an easy way to just pass the current user as the user for the service and automatically set the servive up?

OR

Can I create a console app and some how set it to be transparent? Should not be difficult to move it to the start up folder and to make it run all the time. I just wouldn't want users to see it on the taskbar.

Maybe there is some other option I am not thinking of. Simple is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this for installing Windows Service.

1. [Install a .NET windows service without InstallUtil.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255056/install-a-net-windows-service-without-installutil-exe)
2. [How to install a windows service programmatically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358700/how-to-install-a-windows-service-programmatically-in-c)
3. [How do I install a Windows Service programatically with additional args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809243/how-do-i-install-a-windows-service-programatically-with-additional-args)

I don't think we can make console apps transparent, but yes you can make windows forms transparent. Set the opacity to 0% and ShowInTaskbar property to false. Also set the visibility to hidden.

I think the Windows service option is good. Because it is designed to run as background applications.

Comment: Tell me I am wrong. But with a service you have to go into services and set the user to run it, right?

Comment: Is this setting the "ServiceAccount.NetworkService" account to run the service automatically?